# replace HDD with SSD without losing data

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

My laptop is slow and I want to install SSD on it .

I can't use SSD and HDD at same time and i must replace HDD with SSD .

can I replace HDD without reinstalling ubuntu and losing any data ?

Comment: You will then need a caddy or SATA to USB3 cable. Both my cable & caddy (I have both) will work well with SSD but do not have enough power from USB port for HDD. So if you want HDD in caddy, get one with separate power. I prefer new install & restore from your backups. Which should at minimum be /home, list of installed apps and perhaps any system settings you change in /etc (I change grub, but copy files into /home for backup).

Comment: Are the two disks of the same capacity?

Comment: There is just one option , SSD or HDD . HDD is 500gb and SSD will be 256 or 512 gb .used space on HDD is less than 100gb

Comment: Copy all the data on a big usb stick and then boot from a live usb stick (on a different usb stick) and then copy it on the ssd